# 'A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled' and partial state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a parent component that is interested in gathering a list of contacts (name+email):

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import AddContactFn from './components/AddContactFn'

function App() {
    const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([])

    const addNewContact = (newContact) => {
        setContacts([...contacts, newContact])
        
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <AddContactFn newContact={addNewContact} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

through a child component, which renders a form, with two inputs fields and an 'Add' button:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function AddContactFn({ newContact }) {
    const [contact, setContact] = useState({name: ' ', email: ' '})

    const addContact = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (contact.name === ' ' || contact.email === ' ') {
            return
        }
        newContact(contact)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Add Contact</h2>
            <form onSubmit={addContact}>
                <label>Name</label>
                <input
                    type='text'
                    name='name'
                    value={contact.name}
                    placeholder='Name'
                    onChange={e => setContact({ name: e.target.value })}
                />
                <label>Email</label>
                <input
                    type='text'
                    name='email'
                    value={contact.email}
                    placeholder='Email'
                    onChange={e => setContact({ email: e.target.value })}
                />
                <button type='submit'>Add</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I am facing two issues:

1. `Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.`
2. with both input fields containing text, every time the Add button is pressed, only the last edited value is returned to the parent (ie. either 'name' or 'email' is returned, not both)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets fix one at a time

1. The warning:

Try adding a check for the input value like `value={contact.name || ''}`
The [OR ||](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) operator will check if `contact.name` is valid, if so use it otherwise `''`

This is a side effect linked to the second issue

2. The state:

Your **onChange** handler needs to add the previous object properties, currently they are not, so try `onChange={e => setContact(prevState, ({...prevState,  name: e.target.value }))}`

By doing `onChange={e => setContact({ name: e.target.value })}` you are losing all the properties of the state object, and setting the state to only have a name or email property, that is why you get the warning since the name or email are lost.

Since you have two input fields (name & email) you will have to do the same on both:

```
<label>Name</label>
<input
   type='text'
   name='name'
   value={contact.name || ''}
   placeholder='Name'
   onChange={e => setContact(prevState => ({...prevState, name: e.target.value}))}
 />
 <label>Email</label>
 <input
   type='text'
   name='email'
   value={contact.email || ''}
   placeholder='Email'
   onChange={e => setContact(prevState => ({...prevState, email: e.target.value}))}
/>
```

Comment: thanks @Ricardo Sanchez - your suggested solutions have fixed the first issue, and with a bit of tweaking fixed the second one as well. to access 'prevState', setState() needs to pass in an arrow function setState((prevState) => ({/*derived new state based on prevState*/})). so in the context of my code, it should be: onChange={e =>
                            setContact(prevState => ({
                                ...prevState,
                                email: e.target.value,
                            }))
                        }.

Comment: So if you could revise your code slightly accordingly @Ricardo Sanchez I will accept yours as the answer. cheers!

Comment: Great, I forgot to mention you have to do the same for both name and email input fields

Answer (score 1):

When you use `setContact({ name: e.target.value })` (or for the email) you are also setting the other field as undefined. The way I would recommend you did this is:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function AddContactFn({ newContact }) {
    const [name, setName] = useState(' ');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState(' '); 

    const addContact = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (name === ' ' || email === ' ') {
            return
        }
        newContact({ name, email })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Add Contact</h2>
            <form onSubmit={addContact}>
                <label>Name</label>
                <input
                    type='text'
                    name='name'
                    value={name}
                    placeholder='Name'
                    onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label>Email</label>
                <input
                    type='text'
                    name='email'
                    value={email}
                    placeholder='Email'
                    onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                />
                <button type='submit'>Add</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

If you want to keep the state as it currently is then you can just do e.g. `setContact({ ...contact, name: e.target.value })`

Comment: thanks @apokryfos - this has fixed the first issue beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

You are using [**Controlled Input**](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) where you bind the input tag **value** to one of **contact** state property  and the **onChange** event to an arrow function that will update the **contact** state.

Initially, the **contact** state has two properties, which are name, and email.

```js
const [contact, setContact] = useState({name: ' ', email: ' '})
...
return (
  <input
    value={contact.name}
    onChange={e => setContact({ name: e.target.value })}
  />
  <input
    value={contact.email}
    onChange={e => setContact({ email: e.target.value })}
  />
)
```

When the **onChange** event occurs, it will update the **contact** state with a **new object that only has one property**. Here, React will raise a warning as one of the input values detects the change and found that the **binding reference is missing/undefined**. At that moment, your input has become an **Uncontrolled Input**. That's why you got this error:

> Warning: A component is changing a **controlled input** to be
> **uncontrolled**. This is likely caused by the value **changing from a
> defined to undefined**, which should not happen. Decide between using a
> controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the
> component.

To fix it, you can clone the **contact** by using a shallow copy and update your setter like this:

```js
onChange={e => setContact({ ...contact, name: e.target.value })}

onChange={e => setContact({ ...contact, email: e.target.value })}
```

So, whenever **onChange** event occurs, the updated **contact** state will always have two properties both **name**, and **email**. Of course, you can use the other technique, as long as the updated value always has consistent keys and the binding reference remain.

Here is an example:

[image: Edit ecstatic-mclean-9vmjkj]

Comment: beautiful explanation re. shallow copy (a concept I didn't get before) @yohanes. it helped - thank you so much.